# Proving the compact open topology map of a disjoint union is homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> $X,Y,Z$ are topological spaces and $X,Y$ are Hausdorf.
> Prove the homeomorphism over the compact open topology $Map(X \amalg Y,Z) \cong Map(X,Y)\times Map(Y,Z)$

I know that $(f: X \amalg Y \rightarrow Z) \mapsto (f \circ i_{1}, f \circ i_{2})$ where $i_{1},i_{2}$ are the canoncial inclusions.
The universal property tells us that this is well-defined and a bijection. I'm unsure how to further prove this homeomorphism.

Comment: By $Map$ you mean $C$ (*continuous* maps). And by $Map(X,Y)$ you mean $Map(X,Z).$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: I'm not sure how a basis element W[K,U] would look for X and Y being the disjoint union

Comment: Well, what is a compact subset $K$ of the disjoint union?

Comment: Since X and Y are Hausdorf there exists a U and V open such that there intersection is empty. A compact subset of the disjoint union must be open and spans the set so if $X \amalg Y = (x\times \{1\}) \cup (y \times \{2\})$ could it be the subset $\{1,2\}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143162/discussion-between-anne-bauval-and-jordyn-taylor).

Comment: (I left the chat since noone answered) First, you don't need those U,V, nor Hausdorff here. X, Y themselves are open in the disjoint union. Second, I don't understand your notation $(x\times \{1\}) \cup (y \times \{2\})$. Third, try to prove that a compact subset of the disjoint union is simply the union of a compact of X and a compact of Y.